# UE5 WebSockets plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, but in a plugin https://unrealcommunity.wiki/websocket-client-cpp-5vk7hp9e.
The solutions is building successfully in VS, but when I start the project in UE I get
`Plugin 'WebSocketPlugin' failed to load because module 'WebSocketPlugin' could not be loaded. There may be an operating system error or the module may not be properly set up.`

If I comment everything out but the module and the header files it works again.
I get this error again when doing this:

```
const FString ServerURL = TEXT("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/"); // Your server URL. You can use ws, wss or wss+insecure.
const FString ServerProtocol = TEXT("ws");              // The WebServer protocol you want to use.
    
TSharedPtr<IWebSocket> Socket = FWebSocketsModule::Get().CreateWebSocket(ServerURL, ServerProtocol);
```